How can I shield electronic devices against interference from a plasma cutter?
I am trying to build an NC plasma cutter with a 3D printer. This was the setup:
To do some tests I've mounted the plasma torch (Parkside) to the printer's (Creality CR-10) carriage. The button on the torch is a simple contact, so I replaced it with a relay, without an optocoupler, controlled by the printer. The printer itself was live controlled by my laptop through USB.
It all went well until the printer tried to ignite the plasma. The printer's display went blank and rebooted. The laptop crashed and the screen looked like a kaleidoscope. Even my clock, which was like four meters away from the generator, rebooted.
I thought it was just the generator throwing trash into the grid but unplugging the laptop from power outlet didn't make any difference.
I did some research on google and found quite a lot of articles about EM interference and related countermeasures but it was all complicated engineering stuff, beyond the understanding of a rookie electrician like me.
I was hoping to get some practical advice on how to protect my electronics and make the machine work.

can you post a picture of your setup?

EMI issue. Please post schematic and layout.

There are different types of plasma torches. High-frequency and line-frequency AC produce intense RF interference (RFI or EMI) because the arc is broken and struck again many times per second. Even 50 or 60 Hz AC will create high harmonics, because an arc is nonlinear -- it can even oscillate -- and the tank circuit is the wiring. There are also dv/dt voltage spikes. It would be very difficult, if not impossible, to shield such a commercial torch. (If the arc were contained inside the apparatus, as can be done in an atomic hydrogen torch, when the gas is dissociated internally by RF, and only the recombining atoms and ions are expelled, sheilding is simplified.)
If the torch uses direct current, it might be feasible to shield the still-considerable RFI. See this article on a plasma cutter for CNC to see how that was accomplished.
